# Should we use induction step for all possible cases in induction on complexity of formula approach?

Tags: logic, induction

In logic, one approach to proving some property about a formula of a logical language is to use induction on the complexity of that formula. Informally, if $\varphi$ be a formula, when we use induction on the complexity of $\varphi$, we first prove the base step, then show that the statement holds for all possible cases of $\varphi$, that is $\varphi=\neg \psi$, $\varphi=\psi\wedge\chi$ and etc. In the induction step, we assume the statement holds for $\psi$ (induction hypothesis), and show the statement holds for example $\varphi=\neg\psi$ and so on.

My question is, should the induction hypothesis (the statement holds for $\psi$) be used for all possible cases of $\varphi$? Is there something wrong with my proof, if I have special case $\varphi=\psi\rightarrow\chi$ in which the statement holds without using induction hypothesis?

Comment: Not very clear... but if a proof is by induction on the number of connectives, in the induction step we have to consider all cases: unary connectives like $\lnot$, and all binary connectives that are *primitive* (i.e. listed into the syntactical specification of the language). If a connective is introduced as an abbreviation, like e.g. $p \to q =_{def} \lnot p \lor q$, it is not necessary to consider it, because it is already covered by the cases for $\lnot$ and $\lor$.

Answer (score 1):

I would include it in the inductive step, so that the inductive proof nicely follows the recursive definition.

Think of the alternative: Suppose you have a non-inductive prove that the statement holds for any statement of the form $\phi \to \psi$ ... and you have a separate inductive proof that shows the statement holds for any statement whose main connective is not a conditional. OK, then what about the statement $\phi \land (\psi \to \chi)$? Note that this statement is covered by neither proof, because the inductive proof will only build up statements whose main connective is not a conditional, and so will not build up the result for $\psi \to \chi$, and therefore not for $\phi \land (\psi \to \chi)$ either.

Of course, you can save the inductive proof by considering the $\to$ case after all ... but now you're back to a 'full' inductive proof that *does* consider all connectives. The good news is that the $\to$ case should be relatively easy if indeed does not require the inductive assumption.

In sum: I would put the $\to$ case in the inductive step, even if it does not use the inductive assumption.

Comment: Thank you, I needed such advice.